# I am trying to make a simple button in javascript doing two stuff

Tags: javascript, html, button, toggle

I am looking for a way to have two separate operations / functions in the same time

a button ON and OFF

and a button who affect the volume of my video (turn on and off)

I have two scripts but don't know how to make the both in one.

this is the 2 scripts:

```
<button onclick="toggleMute();">Volume</button>
                    
<input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color:blue" onclick="toggle(this);">
                    
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggle(button)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("1").value=="OFF"){
       document.getElementById("1").value="ON";}
    
      else if(document.getElementById("1").value=="ON"){
       document.getElementById("1").value="OFF";}
    }    
</script>
                    
<script>
    function toggleMute() {
        var video=document.getElementById("theplayer")
            if(video.muted){video.muted = false;} 
            else {video.muted = true;}
    };
</script>
```

and this is my video :)

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="muted" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" class="video" id="theplayer" type="video/mp4" width="100%" height="auto" style="display:block; margin:0 ; padding: 0;">
                  <source src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'content-video', true ); ?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

thanks a lot

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  In the code shown, what isn't working as expected?  Which button isn't doing what you expect it to do?

Comment: Why are there two scripts instead of one? Why not include everything in the one.

Comment: Remove the middle two script tags: </script><script>

Comment: @DanMullin Why does that make a difference? All script blocks are run, it doesn't matter whether you merge them into a single block.

Comment: It makes no difference. It was what the op was asking about though. How to combine them.

Comment: @arundeepchohan it's what I want to do and don't know how to do :)

Comment: @David you have two working scripts with tow different button, I'm looking for to mix this in one script and one button :)

Comment: @DanMullin ;))) thanks anyway I like the advert

Comment: @QuentinContent `if(video.muted){video.muted = false;} else {video.muted = true;}` could be just `video.muted = !video.muted;`

Comment: @SaymoinSam changed it, thanks 

and do you have an idea to muted and change the text in the same time ? :)))

Comment: @QuentinContent take a look on my answer I have refactored your code

Comment: @QuentinContent: So what have you tried and what isn't working?  In your code you have a demonstration of how to invoke a function when clicking a button, and how to write code in that function.  So... Have you tried making your "one button" and having it invoke a function and putting your code in that function?  Have you made any attempt to do anything at all?

Comment: @David thanks for answer it, I just finish my button and will post the answer bellow this article in two seconds ,

THANKS EVERYBODY FOR THE HELP I'm a newbie in JS yet and learn with my self, tutorial and you everyday 

<3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have refactored your code

```js
document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
  var states = {"OFF": "ON", "ON": "OFF"};
  this.value = states[this.value];
}              

document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  var video = document.getElementById("theplayer");
  video.muted = !video.muted;
}
```

```html
<button>Volume</button>          
<input type="button" value="ON" style="color:blue">
<br>
<video src="https://res.cloudinary.com/saymoinsam/video/upload/v1541946026/PiratesOfTheCaribbean.mp4" id="theplayer" autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="muted">
</video>
```

Here is another implementation using just a checkbox since it's the more correct input element to use because it's all about on or off

```js
document.querySelector("#volume-switcher").onchange = function() {
  document.querySelector("#theplayer").muted = !this.checked;
}
```

```css
#volume-switcher {
  display: none;
}
#switcher-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#switcher-container:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #666666;
}

#volume-switcher:checked + #switcher-container {
  background-color: #9999ff;
}

#volume-switcher:checked + #switcher-container:after {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="volume-switcher">
<label id="switcher-container" for="volume-switcher"></label>
<br>
<video src="https://res.cloudinary.com/saymoinsam/video/upload/v1541946026/PiratesOfTheCaribbean.mp4" id="theplayer" autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="muted">
</video>
```

Comment: niceee and clear, I learn JS 

I would delete the volume button and just have the ON and Off button who affect your video 

I was not clear before, sorry :///

Comment: this was really helpful to understand the code and the button and the function and everything, because of you I almost finish my button (will post it in two seconds under this article)

Comment: Glad I could help ;), happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everybody and your understanding of my lvl in javascript :))
@saymoinsam was really helpful and I finish the button with is help and yours :

See the all result (with css) on this Codepen : [https://codepen.io/quentindigital/pen/oNxwNrv]

```
    <video src="https://res.cloudinary.com/quentindigital/video/upload/v1598625047/day20-challenge-quentinrenaux_ylqkl7.mp4" id="theplayer" autoplay="autoplay" loop="" muted="muted">
    </video>

<script>
document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
  var states = {"Volume OFF": "Volume ON", "Volume ON": "Volume OFF"};
  this.value = states[this.value];

  var video = document.getElementById("theplayer");
  video.muted = !video.muted;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can reduce duplicated code so `"Volume OFF"` and similar should only be `"OFF"` and so on, and in the line `this.value = states[this.value];` you can add that string since it's always present `this.value = "Volume " + states[this.value];`

Comment: @SaymoinSam understand the path you advert me but I just tried and that give me an "undefined" value after first click (I changed the value in the input too by the full text "Volume Off" and tried without the full text too)

(you can see the test on this https://codepen.io/quentindigital/pen/oNxwNrv )

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot about the initial input value, but I was wondering why don't you use a checkbox and style it as a switcher that would be nice and will make your code much cleaner and optimized

Comment: take a look on my answer I have updated it to work with a styled checkbox instead, you may find it useful

Comment: I play with you code on my code pen and put the button hover all the video with a different design , it’s cool. I wonder if the video play with every brother but it’s working for me. Thanks again @saymoinsam

Comment: By the way   the final : https://codepen.io/quentindigital/full/oNxwNrv